# Convert string second including timezone to a formated string date

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to dynamically convert a string seconds like below to a string date.

> '1545239561 +0100'

The problem is the timezone inserted at the end, and I can't find any python time object method using the good format to retrieve the date from this string.

My tries :

```
>>>seconds = '1545239561 +0100'
>>>time.strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M%S-%f', datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
>>>time.strptime(seconds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 559, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '1545239561 +0100' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
>>>time.strptime(seconds, "%S +%Z")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 559, in _strptime_time
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '1545239561 +0100' does not match format '%S +%Z'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to process both those value separately and merge them into single `datetime`:

```
>>>from datetime import datetime
>>>s = '1545239561 +0100'
>>>seconds, offset = s.split()
>>>datetime.fromtimestamp(int(seconds)).replace(tzinfo=datetime.strptime(offset, "%z").tzinfo)
datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 19, 17, 12, 41, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes @mfrackwiak...

I did this

```
>>> epoch = "1545239561 +0100"
>>> seconds, offset = epoch.split()
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(int(seconds)).replace(tzinfo=datetime.strptime(offset, "%z").tzinfo).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S-%Z')
'2018-12-19 18:12:41-UTC+01:00'
>>>
```

Comment: Not really wrong anwser as you were still taking the good approch, the subtility here was the timezone inserted behind

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below example :

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
# split the timevalue and offset value
ss = '1545239561 +0100'.split()
format =  "%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S"
# calculate the hour and min in the offset
hour  = int(ss[1][0:2])
min =   int(ss[1][2:])
# calculate the time from the sec and convert it to datetime object
time_from_sec = datetime.strptime(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ss[0])).strftime(
    format), format)
# add the offset delta value to the time calculated
time_with_delta_added = time_from_sec + timedelta(hours=hour,minutes=min)
print(time_with_delta_added)
```

**Output :**

```
2018-12-19 12:22:41
```

Comment: Yes but I want the timezone included, look at my  answer above